# Enzyme reference error - unable to access window functions

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, jsdom

I have the following function in main.js (loaded with node.exe):

```
window.onload = () => {
    window.getString = function () {
        <Do something>
        return value;
    };
}
```

Following is my test case written using Enzyme and Mocha

```
import "jsdom-global/register";
import React from "react";
import {mount} from "enzyme";
import Sessions from "./Sessions";
describe("Testing Sessions Page", () => {
    it('should work', () => {
        let wrapper = mount(<Sessions/>);
    });
});
```

In my Sessions component, written using React framework, I use the `getString` method. When I run my test, it gives `ReferenceError: getString is not defined`. How do I make the window objects accessible in the test code?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `jsdom-global`, the window object is defined but the getString is not, so either:

a) define the `getString` method in your tests before the describe block:

`window.getString = () => {};`

b) stub `getString` with `sinon` if you want to test its invocation

`sinon.stub(window, 'getString');`

c) just include the `main.js` in you tests:

`import './main.js';`